# new kernel and exfatprogs do not support same mount options as exfat-utils

Tags: permissions, fstab, exfat

On multiple machines at work and at home, I multiboot between one or two flavors of Linux and a few flavors of Windows. In order to keep my data centralized regardless of what OS I'm in, I use an exFAT partition; in Linux, I mount it on startup in /etc/fstab.

Using default mount options in /etc/fstab results in the contents of the mount having root:root ownership - which isn't a deal-breaker, but is slightly inconvenient. Therefore, prior to now, in fstab I have used the following mount options (which I arrived at many years ago partially through Google, and partially through trial-and-error), which allow me rw permissions as a non-root user:

```
users,uid={my username},gid=users,umask=0002,utf8=true
```

This has worked beautifully for years.

However, I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 on one of my machines, and these options are apparently no longer considered valid (to the point that I get dropped into emergency mode if I try to boot with that fstab entry enabled). My understanding is that the kernel has exFAT rw support allegedly built into it, and that exfatprogs is also around for more sophisticated tasks like creating, labeling, and fsck-ing such file systems. However, none of this seems to support the uid and gid mount options that have been available throughout various versions of exfat-utils, fuse-exfat, etc.

Does anybody have any knowledge that would help me here, i.e. 22.04-compatible ways of mounting exFAT partitions such that I have rw access as a non-root user?